# GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount() returns null on release build

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm trying to add google sign-in to my android app. Everything works fine on debug build. But when I push the apk for internal testing on Google Play it throws Google SignIn API Exception 10. Should I add anything extra to my console?

So far I've done the following things,

1. Created new firebase project
2. Added SHA-1 to firebase console.
3. Downloaded google-services.json from firebase and copied to app
   folder.
4. On my https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
   page everything is automatically filled by firebase. So, I didn’t do
   anything there.
5. Add all required libraries to android project

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   ```
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
           SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
           signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

           GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                   .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                   .requestEmail()
                   .build();
   mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, so);
   }
   ```

   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   ```
       // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
       if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
           // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
           // a listener.
           // Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
           Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
           try {
               // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
               GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
               Log.e(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
               //firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
           } catch (ApiException e) {
               // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
               Log.e(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
           }
           handleSignInResult(task);
       }
   }
   ```

HandleSignInResult;

```
 private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> 
   completedTask) {
                String personName = "", personEmail = "", aid = "";
                 Uri personPhoto = Uri.parse("");
                // GoogleSignInAccount acct = 
    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
                  GoogleSignInAccount acct = completedTask.getResult();
                  if (acct != null) {
                     personName = acct.getDisplayName();
                     personEmail = acct.getEmail();
                     personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
                     aid = acct.getId();
                     Log.e("ID_TOKEN", acct.getIdToken() + "");
                 } 
      }
```

Comment: Have you added the release SHA-1 to your console?

Comment: Yes. Using the debug.keystore

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but if you have Google Play Signing enabled, you might need to add the SHA-1 that you can find in the Google Play console under Release -> Setup -> App integrity. Worth a try.

Comment: @lasagnakid77 should I replace my debug.keystore SHA-1 with this one from google play console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now working after I added the SHA-1 from Google Play console under Release -> Setup -> App integrity as @lasagnakid77 mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Nice, glad it helped. I had the same issue with google drive API.

Comment: I tried replacing the Google Play Singing SHA-1 key to firebase re-downloaded the googleserverice.json and run and still has this issue.

I am try to get the email and display name with Google Fit API